# Is it harmful to connect multiple External Hard Drives to my laptop?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I wonder if connecting two or three External Hard Drives to my laptop can cause any harmful effect on my laptop or external hard drives?
the external hard drives have 5TB of storage capacity each one.

My laptop: core i7 8GB RAM 1TB storage windows 10

Comment: As long as there are operating off of a USB hub and have independent power, which they would have to have, I don't see how they could possibly harm your laptop. What makes you suspect so?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long Answer: I regularly have multiple external had drives attached to my laptop. None have ever failed although the internal hard drive did ...